# ID3 tag editor with support for STDIN

Tags: command-line-interface, id3, id3v2

Does anyone know a CLI ID3 tag editor that accepts tags from standard input? I'm thinking something like [massren](https://github.com/laurent22/massren) but for ID3 editing.

Comment: "massren" does not work thru STDIN, but instead just creates a temporary file. STDIN would mean I could run `massren.exe < anyfile.txt` but the manual nowhere mentions such a use. For both use cases I don't know any metadata editor.

Comment: I know what STDIN is. The point of this is that I want to use the power of multiple cursors in my editor to quickly generate a long list of tags and then pass it to the id3 editor. But thanks for confirming that you haven't come across one.